# Instantiating a type-constrained generic class without subclassing it

Tags: c#, generics, generic-constraints

**Background**

[Skip to **Question** if you're not interested in the background]

I stumbled across this generic class definition when reading the other day, and it stumped me for some time:

```
public abstract class Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>
```

I was puzzled as to how `T` on `Entity<T>` could be of Type `Entity<T>` itself. It seemed some sort of bizarre recursive constraint.

I then realised that this constraint could be satisfied by subclassing (which is, of course, what `abstract` is demanding of the class):

```
public class Deriver : Entity<Deriver>
```

Here, type `T` is garanteed to be of type `Entity<T>` because `Deriver` derives from `Entity<Deriver>`.

**Question**

Anyhow, it led me to wonder, if the class was not abstract, could we instantitate it directly?

So given

```
class Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>
```

Can we instantitate `Entity<T>` directly?

Obviously we can't say:

```
Entity<SomeClass> e = new Entity<SomeClass>();
```

Because `SomeClass` doesn't satisfy the constraint `where T : Entity<T>`.

Ignoring the obvious "Why would you want to do that?" is this essentially is a way of ensuring a class is dervied before you can use it without using the `abstract` keyword?

Comment: I would call it "type system hell" :)

Comment: Eric Lippert's classic blog post on the subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx. TL;DR: no, it's not used as a demand to derive (`abstract` already does this pretty well). It's used as an attempt to provide type safety in certain situations involving class hierarchies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That assumption is not correct. The following will compile:

```
var e = new Entity<Deriver>();
```

Comment: You sure? I've just tried it and it reports the error: `The type 'Deriver' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Entity<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Deriver' to 'Entity<Deriver>'`

Comment: @JamesWiseman: For the definition of `Deriver` given above it does compile. For some random `SomeClass` it does not.